# Emacs/aucTeX ignores local variables

Tags: auctex, local-variables

I am using emacs 29.2 (installed via brew) and auctex (14.04) on a Mac (12.7.4). My .emacs file shows: `'(enable-local-variables :t)`

I have the following at the end of a TeX file:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

but nothing changes -- the file is compiled with the default engine, XeLaTeX. Also tried the first-line form:

```
%% -*- coding: utf-8;mode: latex;TeX-engine: luatex;TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape";TeX-master: t; -*-
```

to no effect.

I initiate a TeX run with `C-c C-a`. This worked with non-brew emacs in the past, but I've clearly missed something.

Comment: Local variables are only read when you open the file: kill the buffer and open it again - or run `M-x normal-mode`.

Comment: @NickD Yes, that's the point: When I open the file, the local variables are not read: lualatex is not run.

Comment: @sgmoye - Do you really have `'(enable-local-variables :t)` in your init file, i.e., a colon before `t` as **`:t`** or is it a typo?

Comment: Besides, I think is something is cheesy because AUCTeX starts `xelatex` which is not the default compiler.  Can you please try to start Emacs as `emacs -Q`, then in `*scratch*` buffer, eval the following `(progn (setq debug-on-error t) (package-initialize t) (package-activate 'auctex))` (i.e., set the cursor after the last `)` and hit `C-x C-e`) and then open your .tex file and try it again? Also do `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` to check you don't have any other AUCTeX installation/files sitting on your HD.

Comment: I will remove the question. Briefly: Apparently an update to emacs rendered a line in my .emacs file erroneous -- everything worked (no problems opening emacs and TeXing worked). When I removed the offending line, my problem with local variables went away. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: What was the offending line?

Comment: (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'aggressive-indent)

Comment: I commented out the  line and everything just worked. I just un-commented it: no error message (?!) but local variables are not working in TeX.

Comment: @sgmoye - What happens if you try this instead?  `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (aggressive-indent-mode 1)))`

Comment: @ArashEsbati I will try that, though I have just discovered that what worked earlier today no longer does: **only in TeX files, local variables are not read in.** It worked briefly this morning, and now does not. I have no idea what may or may not have changed.

Comment: @sgmoye - Please try the recipe I provided with `emacs -Q` upthread and see if your .tex file works as expected.